# Why does Joel want to know my full name when I sign in with Google?

Tags: feature-request, privacy

Previously when I would sign in to SO with my Google account I was notified that I would be permitting my email address to be shared with the site.

That was fine. But it became slightly more intrusive recently. Now I am notified that the site would like to

> View your email address
>
> View your basic info

Where "basic info" is expanded to mean

> View your full name, profile picture and profile URL
>
> View any publicly available information on your Google+ profile (if
>   you have one or create one in the future)
>
> Learn more about your Google+ profile.

I don't understand why I need to provide these things to SO.

I would not like to provide my full name to StackOverflow. Please remove this requirement when signing in.

Comment: Why would you like to create a new account when you already have one?

Comment: Some day I'll figure out why people use a free service that readily discloses information that they want to keep a secret.  That day is not close yet.